# How can i center a widget between two column children?

Tags: flutter

I have a column which contains 3 children.

How can i place a widget (red rectangle) on top of this column and center it between the second and the last child?

This is what i try to achieve:

[image]

Comment: What is the use-case? This is not something that you can naturally achieve using widgets

Comment: 1-3 are buttons which lead to further functions. The red rectangle widget should be shown, when the user is not logged in (=overlay for buttons 2&3). Buttons 2&3 are in disabled state, but i also need this rectangle for a message box.

I have achieved it with a Stack-widget and margin-value, but i prefer a solution with "real center" between those two widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap Widget 2 & 3 in a `Stack`, then in that `Stack` have a `Center` Widget with the Red Widget inside of it.

This would only work if 2 & 3 are the same size though...

Answer (score 0):

You can create something like this,

```
Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: null,
                  child: Text("ONE"),
                ),
                Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: null,
                          child: Text("TWO"),
                        ),
                        RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: null,
                          child: Text("THREE"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
```

- Column

  - Button
  - Stack
  - Column

    - Button
    - Button
  - Container(Red Area) Wrapped with Align Widget and Align by the center.